# Webform file upload with condition

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform with file upload element.  This works fine as long as the file upload element does not have a condition tied to it.  Without the condition, one can see that the selected file was uploaded.  With the condition, the file does upload, but the page does not update showing the uploaded file.  It took me a while to realize that

1. The file was indeed uploading
2. the condition was causing this behavior

I saw that there was a ticket about this exact issue for drupal 7 and it was marked as won't fix.  I wasn't sure if this meant that it wouldn't be fixed just for Drupal 7 or does this apply to Drupal 8 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution.  Since there were multiple elements that depended on the same condition for visibility, I realized I could put them into a fieldset and define the condition for the fieldset instead.  This did the trick.